# Expensive operations and threading in XNA games

Tags: xna, multithreading

There's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread), it's highest voted answer got me curious about the many ways of threading games.

My game has *input update*, *game logic update*, *user interface update* and *expensive operations* methods. Usually the game runs smoothly, but sometimes the user triggers a very expensive method that makes the game freeze for a few seconds, which is of course unacceptable for release, but the method serves development purposes. I hope the freezing can be resolved by threading, so that expensive method may be used in release.

Everyone says the UI thread must have the highest priority, but I'd like it to be second to the input update thread, so the interface (as well as player controls) is as responsive as it can be. But maybe I'm wrong and it doesn't work as I'm imagining, I haven't really succeeded in trying out either way, since XNA is a bit different from a normal C# application (always running Update method instead of just going down the code).

Which threading option (`ThreadPool`, `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker`) should I use (and how) to achieve maximum responsiveness, while not letting the game freeze when doing occasional expensive operations?

---

Stuff to read on threading:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837962/asynchronous-delegates-vs-thread-threadpool
- http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Instead of complicating things with multithreading for what seems to be a development-only operation, have you tried doing something like time slicing your "expensive operation".  That is, to separate out the work across several frames to make it have less of a performance impact?

Comment: A simplified version of that method will be a part of the game world update method, but it still can take enough time for user to see artifacts. I wasn't able to chop it into pieces good enough to not cause freezing and yet finish on time. Besides, there will be more parts of world update, which will only make it worse and harder to regulate manually. So I thought why not do that in a thread.

Comment: How often does the operation occur? Can you simply dim the screen down and display 'Please wait...'? If it's just a development thing and it doesn't happen very often, this can be a quick implementation and save a lot of threading head-ache.

Comment: I'm so into threading head-ache! The operation is game world update, so it's gonna happen every now and then, it runs for about 4 seconds and has to be run every 30 seconds. I'd like to run it more often, though. I tried putting it into a `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker`, and it still causes severe lags, but over time, instead of a constant freezing. Maybe there are some parameters to tune them, but I couldn't find a nice tutorial that tells me how to do this without causing lags.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to profile and modify whatever operation blocks so that you can execute it in a small timeframe (10ms) over multiple frames. For example, if your world is 100k objects, update, say, 100 per frame (100 frames = up to date)

Comment: Isn't there a way all heavy updating can be done in threads while not freezing the UI?

Comment: Have you considered not running *four separate threads*? Unless your CPU has 4 cores on it (and most people don't these days), some of your threads are going to step on each other. You should really only need 3: one for your visualization (it should handle rendering, sound, and input), one for game logic, and then one for whatever your heavy thing is.

Comment: No, that's four categories of methods, there are only two threads: one main and the other one only appears for a short period, but still it manages to hog some resources from the main thread, which confuses me, as I was expecting it not to do that.

Comment: [Coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) are another alternative. In my opinion, they are the easiest concurrency model to understand.

Comment: @user1306322 I'm not sure I mentioned it in one of your other questions about input. But in XNA you need to be polling for input on the main thread only, you can't have an "input update thread"!

Comment: @AndrewRussell I'm not, though why is that?

Comment: I think it's some kind of win32 thing - something about per-thread message queues. I'm not 100% sure about the details. But it is specifically called out in [this presentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16477) by original XNA lead Shawn Hargreaves.